# Bound ConverterParameter always get null at converter

Tags: c#, data-binding, uwp

I have an UserControl called EngrNumberBox, which function is to receive a number in a Textbox, and convert it to a Engineering number notation. Example: User puts 0.0123456 , after losing focus, the Textbox changes format to the number and displays 12.345m. Another example: 12345 --> 12.345K
For that I wrote a Struct called EngrNumber, that behaves like a floating number, composed by 1) a decimal field (the Mantissa), and 2) a String field for the prefix (the Exponent).

There is a Converter used by the Textbox, that converts between String and EngrNumber.
I want to give this EngrNumberBox the property for allow or disallow negative numbers. If negative numbers are not allowed, and user puts a negative number in the Textbox, the control just turns it positive and show that in the Textbox as soon focus is lost. 
So I tried to use the converter parameters, as a bool value representing AllowNegativeNumber. But at run time the parameter always get null, I'm having trouble binding the parameter correctly:

Below is the XAML of the UserControl:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="Transition.CustomControls.EngrNumberBox"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Transition.CustomControls"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local1="using:Transition"
    mc:Ignorable="d" x:Name="control"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <local1:EngrConverter x:Key="engrConverter"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <TextBox Style="{StaticResource EngrNumberBoxStyle}" 
                 x:Name="txtBox"  
                 IsSpellCheckEnabled="False"
                 IsTextPredictionEnabled="False" Width="100"
                 AllowDrop="False"  InputScope="AlphanumericFullWidth"
                 Text="{x:Bind Value, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource engrConverter}, ConverterParameter={Binding AllowNegativeNumber, Mode=OneTime} }"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

below is the associated CS

```
public sealed partial class EngrNumberBox : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public EngrNumber Value
    {
        get { return (EngrNumber)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Value"));
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Value",
            typeof(EngrNumber), typeof(EngrNumberBox), new PropertyMetadata(EngrNumber.one()));

    public bool AllowNegativeNumber
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(AllowNegativeNumberProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(AllowNegativeNumberProperty, value);
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("AllowNegativeNumber"));
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AllowNegativeNumberProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("AllowNegativeNumber",
            typeof(bool), typeof(EngrNumberBox), new PropertyMetadata(false));

    public EngrNumberBox()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

And the converter:

```
public class EngrConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        //number to string
        if (value == null) return "";
        EngrNumber engrNumber = (EngrNumber)value;

        return engrNumber.ToString();

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        //string to number
        String valueString = (String)value;

        if (valueString == "")
            return EngrNumber.one();
        else
        {
            EngrNumber output;
            try
            {
                output = EngrNumber.ConvertFromString(valueString);
            }
            catch { output = EngrNumber.one(); }

            bool allowNegativeNumber = (bool)parameter;

            if (!allowNegativeNumber) output.makePositiveSign();

            return output;
        }
    }
}
```

No matter what I do, the converter method ConvertBack (String to number) always get a null parameter value (and so it crashes with an exception). I think the problem is in the Binding of the parameter, tried many things, but beats me..
What can I do?

Comment: I am afraid you can't bind to the ConverterParameter property because it's not a dependency property.

Comment: @mm8 is spot on here, a bindable property should be a dependency property on your user control.

Comment: what if I make the converter inherit from DependencyObject, and then give it a DependencyProperty?, perhaps I can declare two converters in the XAML of the UserControl, one that can allow negatives, and the other yes.

Comment: For your app's requirement, I don't think you need to use the `ConverterParameter` to achieve it, just get the textbox value and judge whether it is negative numbers then return the positive value in your convert should be well.